# header/data columns are not aligned with jQuery dataTables, bootstrap 2.3.2 and horizontal scrolling enabled

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, datatables

Enabling horizontal scrolling with dataTables and using bootstrap 2.3.2 causes the header and data columns alignment not to be synced - dataTables use two separate tables to provide horizontal scrolling.

See this example:
HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <table id="teamTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Team Member</th>
                        <th>Balancing Team &amp; Individual Priorities</th>
                        <th>Conscientiousness</th>
                        <th>Relating to Others</th>
                        <th>Preference for Teamwork</th>
                        <th>Problem Solving</th>
                        <th>Effort</th>
                        <th>Relying on Others</th>
                        <th>Balancing Work Tasks &amp; Relationships</th>
                        <th>Work Life Balance</th>
                        <th>Assertiveness</th>
                        <th>Time Urgency</th>
                        <th>Pacing Style</th>
                        <th>Resolving Conflict</th>
                        <th>Avoiding Judgement</th>
                        <th>Seeking Approval</th>
                        <th>Learning</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tableBody">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Alexandra Slater</td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Team Focus</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Preparer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Relationship Prioritizer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Balanced Worker</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Enthusiastic Theorist</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Marathon Runner</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Three Musketeer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Relationship Builder</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Work-Life Balancer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Behind The Scenes</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Measured Progresser</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Last Minute</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Adaptor</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Hidden Light</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Diamond</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Eternal Student</a></p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>MIKE FEENEY</td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Team Balancer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Work Horse</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Relationship Prioritizer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Balanced Worker</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Enthusiastic Theorist</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Marathon Runner</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Independent</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Relationship Builder</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Work-Life Balancer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Part of the Cast</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Sprinter</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Last Minute</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Persuader</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Revealer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Sparkler</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Eternal Student</a></p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Gary Crowe</td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Team Balancer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Preparer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Relationship Prioritizer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Team Player</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Enthusiastic Theorist</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Marathon Runner</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Double Checker</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Relationship Builder</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Work-Life Balancer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Part of the Cast</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Measured Progresser</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Steady</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Adaptor</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Revealer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Sparkler</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Eternal Student</a></p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Josh Rammell</td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Team Focus</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Preparer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Go with the Flow</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Team Player</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Enthusiastic Theorist</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Marathon Runner</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Double Checker</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Relationship Builder</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Work-Life Balancer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Behind The Scenes</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Measured Progresser</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Last Minute</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Persuader</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Revealer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Diamond</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Eternal Student</a></p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Luke Uijtenhaak</td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Team Focus</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Preparer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Relationship Prioritizer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Team Player</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Reluctant Philosopher</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Marathon Runner</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Three Musketeer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Relationship Builder</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Work-Life Balancer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Behind The Scenes</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Measured Progresser</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Last Minute</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Persuader</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Revealer</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Diamond</a></p></td>
                        <td><p><a href="#">Eternal Student</a></p></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
        var tableId = 'teamTable';

        var oTable = $('#' + tableId).dataTable({
            "sScrollX": "100%",
               <!--  "sScrollXInner": "150%", -->
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "bPaginate": false
        });

    <!--    new FixedColumns(oTable); -->
```

Here is the test case on JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/tazmaniax/KFxbL/, and the associated debug info http://debug.datatables.net/unovum

In this test case I've used datatables 1.9.4 with the latest datatables bootstrap css and js files (https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/tree/master/integration/bootstrap/2). I've also tested with dataTables 1.10 without any improvement.

Ultimately I would like to also have "sScrollXInner": "150%" and FixedColumns enabled but doing this just makes it much worse.

I've cross posted this to the dataTables forum, http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/52776#Comment_52776

#### UPDATE 15/10/2013:

Apparently the issue is down to a bug in Chrome in the M30 branch that was introduced as part of an optimisation. A fix is now being circulated.
See http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/17714#Item_15
See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=290399

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem when I load your fiddle.  Headers and data scroll together.  Chrome on OSX 10.8.5.

Comment: Looks okay here also - chrome, FF and opera.

Comment: @Daiku thanks for checking the fiddle, what version of Chrome were you using?

Comment: @davidkonrad what OS and version of Chrome were you using? thx

Comment: ubuntu and chrome version 18.0.1025.168

Comment: Chrome Version 30.0.1599.69 Mac OSX 10.8.5

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with same issue and after reading many post here is how problem was "fixed".

- Add into CSS:

  `.scrollStyle { overflow-x:auto; }`
- Add in the view after call dataTable:

  `jQuery('.dataTable').wrap('<div class="scrollStyle" />');`

Eg.
    oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
    });

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
});
jQuery('.dataTable').wrap('<div class="scrollStyle" />');
```